# Barcode Code128 and Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, office365, barcode-printing

I'm trying to get barcode Code 128 to work in Microsoft Word.  We want e-mail addresses to be converted to a barcode and we're using Code 128 because Code 39 doesn't handle special characters (we have _ in our e-mail addresses).

We want the following data on the label:  FirstName LastName and E-mail address (which needs to be the barcode)

I tried using the Code 128 font and the barcode scanner just won't read it.  I also tried the following code:
{DISPLAYBARCODE "john_doe@domain.org" CODE128 \h 500}

If I can get this to work,  I will be using Mail merge and use the MERGEBARCODE string.

I press CTRL+F9 to get the curly brackets.

What am I doing wrong?  BTW, I'm using h 500 to fit the barcode within the label.
Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

M

Comment: You need to calculate code128 checksum. Code 39 is simpler :) Extended 3of9 should support undescore, alhtough this may depend on scanner setup.

Comment: Thanks - looked into checksum.  Seems quite daunting.  I'll Extended 3of9.